# rails 4 should i use call back filter or concerns for this

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database-schema, activemodel

I want to store url's but extract the base url and store it in different table of its own.

url: `example.com/this-is-worth-saving` 
base url: `example.com`

**URL** table:

```
+----+-----+-------------+
| id | url | base_url_id |
+----+-----+-------------+
```

**Base_url** table:

```
+----+----------+
| id | base_url |
+----+----------+
```

Should I use the `before_create` callback in rails to check to see if the `base_url` already exist in the `base_url` table and 
if it does then grab the `id` and place it in the `url`'s tables `base_url_id` 
else create the new record the grab the `id`.

OR

Is there a better solution or schema design perhaps.

I've heard many arguments against the use of callback filters in rails ( 4 ).

Basically I want the `base_url_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callbacks are a giant debate in the Rails world.  I like them, but I also use them only when absolutely necessary.  In this case, I don't think you need callbacks.

I'd recommend using `find_or_create_by!` on your "base_url" table...  Assuming your table is called `BaseUrl`, you could do:

`@base_url = BaseUrl.find_or_create_by!(:base_url => params[:base_url])`

Again, this assumes the name of your table is `BaseUrl` and you're using incoming params which contain a key of `base_url`.  You'd want to modify the above code to fit your needs, but I think `find_or_create_by!` is what you want, as this will either:

a. Return an existing record with that `base_url`, or
b. Create a new record with that `base_url`.